# Angular - Set textarea rows base on the number of rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I am trying to set `textarea` rows property to the numer of `rows` in the text.
Here is the `textarea`:

```
<textarea rows = "countRowsInText(response.simLog)" cols = "200" style = "overflow:hidden">{{response.simLog}}</textarea>
```

Ant the `countRowsInText()` function:

```
$scope.countRowsInText = function(text){
  var numerOfRowsInText = text.split(\/r\n|\r|\n).length; //rows number - 500
  console.log(numerOfRowsInText); //row number
  return numerOfRowsInText;
}
```

And it doesn't work, shows only 2 rows.
Thanks.

Comment: it looks like your function receives a `text` argument and it's not being passed

Comment: editing it, but I think it will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firs guess, {{}} is missed and it should be:

```
<textarea rows = "{{countRowsInText(response.simLog)}}" cols = "200" style = "overflow:hidden">{{response.simLog}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller u can use:

```
 var txtArea = document.getElementById('ptest').value.split('\n');    
    $scope.lines = txtArea.length;
```

then you can use lines in text-area

```
<textarea rows = "{{lines}}" cols = "200" style = "overflow:hidden">{{response.simLog}}</textarea>
```

Comment: there is no jQuery on this site, pure angular.